# Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.driver'

Tags: mysql, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am a Spring MVC beginner using Tomcat 9 with Eclipse to run a spring application. I receive the following error at run time.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page [/WEB-INF/views/listOrganization1.jsp] at line [13]

    10: </head>
    11: <body>
    12:     <h1>Listing organizations using JSTL SQL tag</h1>
    13:     <sql:query var="rs" dataSource="jdbc/springdb">
    14:         SELECT * FROM organization
    15:     </sql:query>
    16:     


    Stacktrace:
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:588)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:314)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


    Root Cause
    javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.driver'"
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:669)
        org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.listOrganization1_jsp._jspService(listOrganization1_jsp.java:156)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:314)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


    Root Cause
    javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.driver'"
        org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.getConnection(QueryTagSupport.java:285)
        org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.doStartTag(QueryTagSupport.java:168)
        org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.listOrganization1_jsp._jspx_meth_sql_005fquery_005f0(listOrganization1_jsp.java:180)
        org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.listOrganization1_jsp._jspService(listOrganization1_jsp.java:135)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:314)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

But `mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar` already exists in the project as a Maven dependency

[image]

And context.xml has for the Tomcat already has the database information as a resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
--><!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application --><Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <Resource name="jdbc/springdb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
               username="devuser" password="$Data4Dev" driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_db?useSSL=false"/>

</Context>
```

As per the response to another question here, I have also added mysql-connector jar to the run time configuration of the Tomcat 9 server.
[image]

I also deleted the repositories in C:\Users\user1.m2\repository multiple times, closed and opened Eclipse and updated Maven for project - nothing has worked and I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Try capitalising the `d` in `driver` at the end of `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.driver`.

Comment: You should not use MySQL Connector/J 6.0.6. It is a development/test version of the **abandoned** Connector/J 6 branch (they continued in the Connector/J 8 development branch that is also not yet released). The latest version of MySQL is still 5.1.44

Comment: Also, the sql tag library should never be used. If you're executing SQL queries from inside your views, you're really missing the whole point of MVC. The controller gets data from the database, stores it in the model, and gives the control to the view, which displays data found in the model. That's the basic principle of MVC.

Comment: My previous comment should have read _"The latest version of MySQL Connector/J is still 5.1.44"_

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for info. Shall update it on my project.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, this was just a quick way of seeing an output in one of the sections of the Spring MVC course I am doing. Won't be doing this when I start developing actual applications.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was fixed by making the change suggested by Luke Woodward.

Answer (score 0):

Check the MySQL connector jar version added in the build path libraries. I have added old jar in build path libraries. This was fixed by changed the jar in the build path libraries.

It may not be the case for you. Because Maven will automatically add the jars to the build path libraries.

The above answer is applicable for the people who manually created the projects without the help of maven.